# Mi función de JavaScript tarda más de 12000ms. ¿Cómo puedo mejorar el rendimiento?

Tags: javascript

mundo. Con mi primera duda acerca de JavaScript.

**Contexto:** Estoy resolviendo problemas de JavaScript, según la plataforma que uso para practicar (edabit) son correctas mis respuestas, pero pasados 9 tests correctos, me marca error por tardar mas de 12000ms.

**¿Podrían decirme cuales son las mejores prácticas para el problema?**

**Problema:** Dado un n determinar si tiene **exactamente 3 divisores**

```
function isExactlyThree(n) {
    let divisors = []
    
    for(let i = 1; i <=  n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0){
            divisors.unshift(2)
        }
    }
    if (divisors.length == 3){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Ejemplos de resultados:**

```
isExactlyThree(4) ➞ true
// 4 has only 3 divisors: 1, 2 and 4

isExactlyThree(12) ➞ false
// 12 has 6 divisors: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12

isExactlyThree(25) ➞ true
// 25 has only 3 divisors: 1, 5, 25
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: [Lectura recomendada](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numbers-exactly-3-divisors/#:~:text=Examples%3A,49%20have%20exactly%20three%20divisors.) sobre este problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12 segundos me parece exagerado para ejecutar el código, que puede ser sujeto de varias optimizaciones rápidas, pero no *luce* tan lento.

La optimización, sin embargo, si bien parte de una ciencia exacta, es más un arte que una ciencia y tu pregunta raya en el borde de lo que puede responderse aquí, pues no hay una respuesta canónica, sin embargo me tomo el riesgo.

A primera vista, yo veo varios problemas.

1. Almacenas un arreglo donde vas acumulando números (que tampoco son los divisores), para finalmente contar los elementos y desechar el arreglo. No hace falta el arreglo entonces y siempre va a ser más *barato* llevar un simple contador, sobre todo si la cantidad de elementos en el arreglo es alta.
2. Siempre sabemos que el número va a ser divisible por si mismo y por la unidad, por lo que podemos excluirlos del ciclo e intentar solo con el resto de números. Esto es importante sobre todo porque no tenemos que llegar al último para aplicar lo que explico en el siguiente item.
3. Una vez un número tiene más de 3 divisores, no importa si son 4 o 400, la función siempre devolverá el mismo resultado, por lo que podemos detenernos al llegar a 4 y devolver *falso*, sin seguir más.

Con estas pequeñas mejoras, debieras obtener resultados sustancialmente más rápidos. Puedes probarlos aquí mismo ejecutando el código en tu propio browser (clic en el botón ejecutar).

```js
function isExactlyThree(n) {
    let numdivisors = 2;
    
    for(let i = 2; i <  n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0){
            numdivisors += 1;
            if (numdivisors > 3) break;
        }
    }
    return (numdivisors == 3);
}

let startTime = performance.now();
console.log('4->' + isExactlyThree(4));
console.log('12->' + isExactlyThree(12));
console.log('25->' + isExactlyThree(25));
console.log('30->' + isExactlyThree(30));
console.log('49->' + isExactlyThree(49));
console.log('51->' + isExactlyThree(51));
console.log('80->' + isExactlyThree(80));
console.log('114->' + isExactlyThree(114));
console.log('169->' + isExactlyThree(169));
console.log('200->' + isExactlyThree(200));
let endTime = performance.now();
console.log(`Tiempo total ${endTime - startTime} ms`);
```

Si quieres llegar más lejos, una posible optimización sería no probar con todos los números, sino solo con los números primos.  Mira el caso del 12, es divisible por 1 y por 12. Fuera de ello, es divisible entre 2, lo que nos da como resultado 6, y entre 3, lo que nos da como resultado 4. Por tanto también es divisible entre 6 y entre 4.

Para llegar al resultado, basta con probar si es divisible entre 2, 3, 5, 7 y 11, que son los primos menores a 12.

Si quieres ir un paso más adelante, puedes restringir la prueba a 2 y 3, pues no tiene sentido probar por números primos mayores a la raíz cuadrada de un número.

Estas optimizaciones, sin embargo, escapan al alcance de esta respuesta.

En mi equipo, las 10 *pruebas* han corrido todas las veces entre 1 y 1.5 ms.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! En mi equipo se corrieron entre 4.0  y 5.0 ms